What are the key quality metrics for large language model releases?
I am a first year PhD student working on improving the release practices of Machine Learning Models, especially pre-trained large language models. I want to understand the above concept for a preliminary learning and opinion from the experts.
I have been reading different articles, but still need experts' opinions.

Stack Overflow is about programming. This is not a programming question. You can try the Data Science Stack Exchange.
